# Returning custom property using with_entities() in flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a custom property on my model. I'm using `with_entities()` to restrict what is returned on my model. For example,

```
class User(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String)
    last_name = Column(String)

    @property
    def slug(self):
       return slugify(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
```

How can I return my model that only has `first_name` and `slug`?

This throws an error:

```
# Try with User.slug
user = User.query.with_entities(User.first_name, User.slug).filter_by(id=1).first()

>> InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<property object at 0x7fdac5483578>'


# Without User.slug
user = User.query.with_entities(User.first_name).filter_by(id=1).first()
print user.slug

>> AttributeError: 'result' object has no attribute 'slug'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using `with_entities()` to only get the User's `first_name` property where the `User.id == 1`, which means the result you get in `user` is not a `User` object but a SQLAlchemy `result` type object.

Also, the reason you can't query on the `slug` property is because it's a property that exists for the Python class, and not as a column in your database table.

I've never used `slugify` before, but it seems that your `slug` property is calculated anyway based on the first and last name.

Perhaps you can rewrite your query to filter by the `first_name` and `last_name`.

```
user = User.query.filter(User.first_name != '', User.last_name == '').filter_by(id=1).first()
```

Also, I think it would be helpful to define your model with a default value for certain properties:

```
class User(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = Column(String, default='')
    last_name = Column(String, default='')

    ...
```